# Filesize stat failed while uploading files

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm facing strange problem right now - *"filesize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php7A38.tmp"* exception. The problem occurs when I'm uploading files in my application built with PHP (Laravel).

Before I'm uploading the files onto the server I'm checking size of files like this (this works very well):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $filesLength; $i++) {
   if(filesize($request['files'][$i]) < 1572865) {
      $file = $request['files'][$i];
      $filename = $imageNumber.'.'.$request['files'][$i]->extension();
      $file = $file->move(public_path().'/app/newsimages/'.$element->id.'/', $filename);
   }
}
```

If I do it like that everything works very well. But the problem is that I have to put this loop in another loop, like this:

```
foreach($somelement as $element) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $filesLength; $i++) {
    if(filesize($request['files'][$i]) < 1572865) {
      $file = $request['files'][$i];
      $filename = $imageNumber.'.'.$request['files'][$i]->extension();
      $file = $file->move(public_path().'/app/newsimages/'.$element->id.'/', $filename);
    }
  }
}
```

In addition to that it crashes **at the second loop of the foreach loop**.

Maybe you have some idea what's wrong in here?

Comment: You can limit file size with validation, why are you checking file size like this ?

Comment: 1. maybe you have two `elements` with same `id`.

Comment: @SagarGautam because diffrent file types can be bigger or smaller. For example img has maximum weight 2MB and the PDF file can weight 15MB.

Comment: @vadim_hr It's not possible.

Comment: there is no chance to detect an error using only this piece of code. check file permission, if you 100% sure that this code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is obvious, in inner loop you move the file, so when you go to next iteration of outer loop file is not there, so for example if you once move the file:

```
$request['files'][0]
```

it's not possible to execute:

```
filesize($request['files'][0])
```

because this file was moved - it doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about it. But I'm attaching `$file = $request['files'][$i];` the file into the `$file` variable and I though that it was cloned. So how can I clone it?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you clone it. When you move file on disk, well it's moved, it doesn't exist so cloning won't help here.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So what will be the best approach to fix the problem? I should copy the file or something like that?

Comment: @forexknight Yes, you can make copy of files however it seems to be quite strange that you are going to copy same file multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it is. I will find another way to avoid duplicating them. Thank you again, and it's quite nice to meet another Marcin at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz Cool, I haven't event noticed you are from Poland too :)